# Image Fade From Dark When Using overflow:hidden?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Watch here.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZpRjPVRHK8w

If im not applying the overflow, the scrollx will exist, but when i apply it, the image fade from dark..why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because the image bigger than 500kb